# JavaFx - What is purpose of StringConverter.fromString in ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

In the follow snippet, What is purpose of StringConverter.fromString here?
I thought converted Object should be the one that I selected, and ComboBox should handle this already, so why is it mandatory to provide a converted Object?

```
public class Person{
      public String firstName;
      public Stirng lastName;
}
@FXML ComboBox<Person> peopleComboBox;
public void setComboBox(){
     // add people to peopleComboBox in here...
     // set object converter
     peopleComboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Person>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Person person) {
            return person.firstName;
        }

        @Override
        public Person fromString(String string) {
            return peopleComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's used for an editable combo box, to convert a value the user types in the text field (a String) to a value for the combo box (a `Person`, in this case). You would typically create a new object here and return it. If the combo box is not editable (the user cannot type in values), you can safely just return null. The implementation you currently have really makes no sense in either case.

Comment: I get it now, I forgot about the editable situation, Thanks!